# Calculate transfer function with Sine generator

Tags: operational-amplifier, sine, circuit-analysis

Given this circuit I would like to know how can I find it's  transfer function.

A method I've considered was to use Node Equations on nodes 1 and 2 , 
and I have a few things that I don't find clear :

1. why do I have to introduce an additional equation with \$V2=0\$ ?
2. Once I find the transfer function in form of \$H(s) = {\dfrac{R1}{R2+Ls+CR1R2s+CLR2s^2}}\$
   I must calculate \$Vu(t)\$ with \$V1=10+cos(t)\$ , the solution states that
   \$Vu(t)= H(0)*10 + Re[H(j)*e^{(jt)}*1]=-10-{\dfrac{1}{2}}{sin(t)}\$
   How does one achieve this result and first of all how does the \$Re\$ part of the transfer function is calculated ?

Thanks a lot for any insight provided.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case a very good approximation to the transfer function can be seen from inspection.  The output impedance of a TL082 is no match for a 1 Ω source.  Therefore the output of this circuit will pretty much just follow the input regardless of anything the opamp tries to do.

Comment: Yes, it is surprising how often instructors will ask their students to analyze an absurd circuit.  One wonders if it was done on purpose as a red herring, by oversight, or because they didn't know themselves.

Comment: @gsills we had the 3rd kind of instructors in my college..

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: the negative feedback makes node 2 equal to the noninverting input, so that's 0 V. Then there flows a current of Vo/R1 through R1, and therefore also through L1 to node 1.